# Merging maven .m2 repositories

Tags: java, maven-2, repository

I have a maven repository in an offline network.

I need to update its contents and merge in another repository .

What is the best method to do this ? I looked at the wagon plugin [Wagon](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/merge-maven-repos-mojo.html) but I am concerned that there may be a better way.

I could replace my local repo with an offline repository manager but the problem still remains , I would have to update that Repo with regular merges from an online source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford to get rid of all metadata (which should recover with the next mvn commands you run) for the time of your operation, just use `rsync`.

If building a concrete repository is not mandatory, consider using [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) and its [groups](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-adding-to-group.html).

Comment: Vicent can you clarify what you mean by "concrete" repository?

Comment: I mean the opposite of "abstract". Nexus allows you to define groups which are kind of facades, with possibly many repositories being used to get artifacts behind the scenes. So depending on your needs, having this kind of delegating, proxy-style repository may not be an option. I assume your question may have been about building a single repository, the type you can put on your USB key...

Comment: Your update is about regular merges: if your Nexus is configured to proxify the changing remote repository, then remote changes *are* merged indeed. The merging process is inherent in the Nexus' grouping mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

[Vincent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179020/merging-maven-m2-repositories/7179169#7179169) is correct, but I would more strongly suggest that you don't do this in the `.m2/repository` directory. That directory is a cache, and should be able to be removed at any time. You should consider setting up a repository manager (such as Archiva, Nexus or Artifactory, or just a HTTP server) and host the repository content there so that you can let Maven manage the `.m2/repository` directory.

Comment: Could please clarify the the "That directory is a cache" portion ? If it is the only repo how can it be a cache? Also I looked at nexus but did not see the ability to merge in another repo.

Comment: In Maven the remote repositories are the canonical source, and the local repository are a cache of what has been retrieved from some remote repository. This is because the remote is designed to be shared between users, while the local is not. Maven will operate with just the cache there, but if you remove things from it, it expects to be able to get them from the remote repository again. Builds will not work for other users if it can not do that, as they don't have the same local repository as you do.

Comment: understood. Question clairfied